# Permanency and its targets

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am playing a character and we are 3 sessions in. We are 11th level and I am a cleric. I am unable to cast [Permanency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency) myself. I can however cast tongues. Tongues is listed under the first grouping of spells.

> You can make the following spells permanent in regard to yourself. You cannot cast these spells on other creatures. This application of permanency can be dispelled only by a caster of higher level than you were when you cast the spell.
>   **Target: Self Only**

When I read this I interpreted it as meaning as long as I was able to cast the spell onto myself I could then have the effect permanencied onto myself by another caster. The DM of the game has read it as meaning I must cast permanency as well as these other spells.

Most of the spells in that section are personal spells, only darkvision and tongues can be cast on other targets which is part of the reason why I thought mine was correct.

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the PFSRD, in the section about [selecting targets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) for spells you cast.

> If the target of a spell is yourself (the Target line of the spell description includes “You”)...

Which means that the cleric can't have anyone else cast Permanency on them, for the spells reserved in the "[self only](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency)" slot. Said Wizard doesn't have to be able to cast Tongues though, so he could cast Permanency on himself while you cast Tongues on him. So that *he* would get the permanent effect out of your spell.

This also means that, if your UMD is high enough, you can use a scroll of Permanency to cast it on yourself. That way circumventing the class requirement, to fulfill the "self only" requirement.

*Edit: Added*
It is also clearly states in the spell description for Permanency itself:

> You can make the following spells permanent in regard to yourself.

Comment: So I had that backwards

Comment: The correct answer is correct so I should mark that down even when I dont like it

Answer (score 11):

The DM is right. You are reading the description of the *Permanency* spell so when it refers to *yourself* that means *the person casting the Permanency spell*.